# Compiling fine, building has errors 'undefined reference to'

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual-functions

I am messing with classes and virtual methods and have run into a problem.
Like the title says, I can compile fine, the problem comes when I try to build and then execute the program.
I am getting these errors:

```
In function 'vehicle::vehicle()';
undefined reference to 'vtable for vehicle'
undefined reference to 'typeinfo for vehicle'
```

I've researched these issues and I have not found a solution to fit my given predicament. I decided to come on here when I couldn't get any where.

Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

class vehicle{
public:

    virtual void openDoor();
    virtual void turnOnFrontLights();
    virtual void turnOnBackLights();
    virtual void shiftGear();
    virtual void openHood(); 
    virtual void openTrunk();
    virtual void checkEngine();
    virtual void moveSeat();
    virtual void useSeatBelt();
    virtual void useBrake();
}; 
class Car : vehicle{
public:
     void openDoor() {std::cout << "I might be able to."<< endl;}
     void turnOnFrontLights() {std::cout << "I might be able to."<< endl;}
     void turnOnBackLights() {std::cout<< "I might be able to."<< endl;}
     void shiftGear() {std::cout <<"I might be able to." << endl;}
     void openHood() {std::cout <<"I might be able to."<< endl;}
     void openTrunk(){std::cout<<"I might be able to." << endl;}
     void checkEngine(){std::cout <<"I might be able to." << endl;}
     void moveSeat(){std::cout << "I might be able to."<< endl;}
     void useSeatBelt(){std::cout << "I might be able to."<< endl;}
     void useBrake(){std::cout << "I might be able to."<< endl;}
};
class MiniCooper : Car{
public:
     void openDoor() {std::cout << "I can."<< endl;}
     void turnOnFrontLights() {std::cout << "I can."<< endl;}
     void turnOnBackLights() {std::cout<< "I can."<< endl;}
     void shiftGear() {std::cout <<"I can." << endl;}
     void openHood() {std::cout <<"I can."<< endl;}
     void openTrunk(){std::cout<<"I can." << endl;}
     void checkEngine(){std::cout <<"I can." << endl;}
     void moveSeat(){std::cout << "I can."<< endl;}
     void useSeatBelt(){std::cout << "I can."<< endl;}
     void useBrake(){std::cout << "I can."<< endl;}
};


int main(){
MiniCooper *miniCooper = new MiniCooper;
cout << "Can you open the doors?" << endl;
miniCooper->openDoor();
return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to learn how virtual methods and classes work, I know it is not the best code but I just want to know why it isn't printing out. I thought I had everything declared properly. I eventually wanted to try and add a truck class that came from vehicle and then add some types of trucks to this program as well, but decided to stop when I could not get output.

Comment: The vehicle class does not have constructor. It is recommended to include it even if it is empty.

Comment: @JaviV Not necessarily. C++ generates a few member functions for you when you don't declare them. These are the default constructor, copy constructor, copy assignement constructor and destructor. If your constructor doesn't do anything, you may as well not declare it.

Comment: I mean recommended from a code style point of view. At least, that is what they taught me :)

Comment: Quick question: I was wondering about a constructor and destructor, when I create them, even if I don't use them, should they have parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You've declared, but not implemented your virtual functions in `Vehicle`.

If you want to leave them not implemented, that's possible. You must declare your virtual functions as pure virtual functions:

```
class vehicle{
public:

    virtual void openDoor()=0;
    //                     ^^
    // Notice the trailing "equal-zero"
    ...
};
```

This makes `Vehicle` an *abstract class* that can't be instantiated, and forces the client code to use derived class of `Vehicle`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That was very insightful. Thank you for showing me the difference between the two!

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement methods in class `vehicle`:

```
class vehicle{
public:

    virtual void openDoor(){}
    virtual void turnOnFrontLights(){}
    virtual void turnOnBackLights(){}
    virtual void shiftGear(){}
    virtual void openHood(){}
    virtual void openTrunk(){}
    virtual void checkEngine(){}
    virtual void moveSeat(){}
    virtual void useSeatBelt(){}
    virtual void useBrake(){}
};
```

or make them pure virtual:

```
class vehicle{
public:

    virtual void openDoor() = 0;
    virtual void turnOnFrontLights() = 0;
    virtual void turnOnBackLights() = 0;
    virtual void shiftGear() = 0;
    virtual void openHood() = 0;
    virtual void openTrunk() = 0;
    virtual void checkEngine() = 0;
    virtual void moveSeat() = 0;
    virtual void useSeatBelt() = 0;
    virtual void useBrake() = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Since there is no implementation for methods in class `Vehicle`, make them `pure virtual`, thus making the class `abstract`.
2. In class `Car`, make the methods `virtual` too, since you are overriding them in the derived class `MiniCooper`.